# How to listion to Audio Position in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-audioplayers

I found this code for **listening to Audio Position ** using package `audioplayers`.
But the `onAudioPositionChanged` features seems to be deprecated now. Does anyone know its replacement or how to listen the audio position using audioplayers in 2023?

**code:**

```
//   //listen to audio position
audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged.listen((newPosition){
  setState(() {
    position = newPosition;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onPositionChanged` on intestate.

```dart
    _positionSubscription = audioPlayer.onPositionChanged.listen(
      (p) => setState(() => _position = p),
    );
```